# Python string in...in syntax

Tags: python

It is strange to see a piece of code using 'str in str in str' syntax, e.g.:

```
>>> 'test' in 'testtest' in 'testtesttest'
True
>>> 'test' in 'testtest' in 'tb3'
False
>>> 'test' in 'testtesta' in 'testtesttest'
False
>>> 'test' in ('testtest' in 'testtesttest')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    'test' in ('testtest' in 'testtesttest')
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

It seems the 'in...in...' is similar to '<...<...' comparison. But a quick google did not guide me to the official answers. Any help?

Comment: I think your guess is correct. "A in B in C" means "A in B and B in C", just like "a < b < c" means "a < b and b < c".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Official answer from the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

```
comp_operator ::=  "<" | ">" | "==" | ">=" | "<=" | "!="
                   | "is" ["not"] | ["not"] "in"
```

The `in` keyword is a comparison operator. And "Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily". Note that this isn't restricted to "value comparisons" (`>`, `==`, etc.).

The code in question checks whether each is a substring of the next item in the chain.